# How can I load a webpage with Google chrome instead of WebView in Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I want to let the user to visit my website by click a button.

However, I want the app to open the google chrome or other external web browser to open the website instead of load the url with WebView.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` --

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.whereever.com/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(myUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to do it on a button click, you will need to put it in the `onClick` method of your `onClickListener`.